# Help to describing a recurrence for $l_n$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

I have to describe a recurrence for $l_n$, the number of lobsters caught in year $n$.

The task says: a hobby fisherman estimates the number of lobsters he will catch in a year as the average of the number he caught in the two previous years.

Describe a recurrence for $l_n$, the number of lobsters caught in year $n$.

I have tried something. It is a homogeneous degree LRR, so the recurrence is: $\displaystyle l_n = \frac{(l_{n-1} + l_{n-2})}{2}$ as it is the average for $2$ years. Have I solved ít correctly?

Comment: This is correct. Which are your doubts?

Comment: It's because I also have to tell how many lobsters the fisherman will expect in year 4

Comment: So the number of lobsters cauaght in year n would be the recurrence I've written

Answer (score 0):

Hint: if you apply the recurrence to $l_3$ you have $l_3=\frac{l_2+l_1}{2}$. Now apply the same recurrence relation and use the last equation to express $l_4$ as a function of $l_2$ and $l_1$.

Comment: Ok, but how to do I calculate how many he can expect in year 4? I know it's l_4= (l_3+l_2)/2

Comment: In the equation for $l_4$, just substitute $l_3$ with the average of $l_1$ and $l_2$.

Comment: He caught 50 in year 1 and 110 in year 2 so the equation will look like:  l_4= (80+110)/2 right?

Comment: and 80 is also the solution for l_n if he caught 50 lobsters in year 1 and 110 in year 2

Comment: Your solution $ l_4= (80+110)/2=95$ is right.

Comment: So it's also correct that the solution for l_n is 80 if he caught 50 lobsters in year 1 and 110 in year 2?

Comment: No, that is the solution for $l_3$. For $l_n$ you have to give the general solution.